# how to store user session into request object in expressjs

Tags: mongodb, express

I am newbie in expressjs and read a very popular MERN project now.After an user(buyer) log into site and place an order which will be added into Mongodb tagged with the user(buyer),the backend code like below:

```
const addOrderItems = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const {
    orderItems,
    shippingAddress,
    paymentMethod,
    itemsPrice,
    taxPrice,
    shippingPrice,
    totalPrice,
  } = req.body

  if (orderItems && orderItems.length === 0) {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error('No order items')
    return
  } else {
    const order = new Order({
      orderItems,
      user: req.user._id,
      shippingAddress,
      paymentMethod,
      itemsPrice,
      taxPrice,
      shippingPrice,
      totalPrice,
    })

    const createdOrder = await order.save()

    res.status(201).json(createdOrder)
  }
})
```

Link:https://github.com/bradtraversy/proshop_mern/blob/master/backend/controllers/orderController.js

But where the `req.user._id` comes from?I check the whole project,some popular backend session or storage tools like `express-session` and `cookie-session`did not installed and used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's comes from [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) package. It will log user with `JWT` and populate the `user` property of the `req` object.

Comment: in `package.json`,no `passport` package installed,please see the package.json:https://github.com/bradtraversy/proshop_mern/blob/master/package.json